# PHP 7 session_start shutting down php -S localhost:8000

Tags: php, session, server

I'm facing a strange error, I have a Git repo which a personal project on witch I usually work on my lunch time or on my free time at home.

If I have the `session_start()` command on the project , when I serve this project using `php -S localhost:XXXX` on my home computer (**PHP5.6** installed) everything runs smoothly but on my workplace computer it shuts down the server ( runs **PHP 7** ).

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Could the server logs shed any light?

Comment: Actually no, the log doesn't have any entry on this, and git bash doesn't share any info, like I've pressed CTRL+C

Comment: ok, found the answer to it and I'll post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

For PHP7 users using Apache, it seems this is a frequent problem.
If you have session.use_only_cookies=0 on your php.ini file, everytime you start your server and do the session_start() command, the server will crash.

Just set use_only_cookies=1 and everything should be fine.

Comment: Apache with `mod_php` or is Apache set up to use `php-fpm`?

Answer (score 0):

Set session.use_only_cookies=1 in php.ini